# How many test methods could be put in a test class run with Theories JUnit4

Tags: testing, junit

It seams that it is unreasonable to put more than one test methods in a test class, since it does not make sense to add two sets of static data points in one class. Is it a best practice to have only one test method in a test class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There are several methods to have multiple Theories in a single test class.

1. You might have `@DataPoints` of different types
2. You might have different sets of `@DataPoints` of the same type (for example one being valid cases and one invalid) and use `assumeThat` to limit a `@Theory` to only use values from one set.
3. You might have `@Test`s as well as `@Theory`s in the same test class
4. You could use `Enclosed` runner to run multiple inner classes each with their own set of exclusive `@DataPoints`

Much of this depends of course on the complexity of the class under test. But I usually mix `@Theory` with `@Test` and in several cases had multiple different `@DataPoints`. A common example of this is a class with multiple setters each taking a different type.

Comment: I appreciate your reply, and:
1. Since @DataPoints are at the class level, it does not make much sense to mix them in one class, just to serve two different test methods.
2. This approach makes more sense because those test methods typically are related.
3. Yes, we can always do it.
4. Enclose is something new to me. I'll try it.